# Stream read return length 0 while stream is open and has valid data in it

Tags: vb.net, stream, audio-converter

I have a bit of a problem : in an winForm app in VS2010 win 7 compiling to x86, I try to do what Alvas.Audio seems to work. See (c# ex:  http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip94) for reference.

```
 Dim data() As Byte = wr.ReadData(second * i, second)
```

The result give me `data.length()=0`. I do not have any exception, I can read format from it and whatever reader I use I got this problem.

EDIT : After some tests, it seems like the uncompressed file I create in the first step (in PCM format, with .wav extension) can not be recognized by the Alvas.audio library for the second step. I must miss something around Audio file markups or something alike.

Here is the code that might be the source (basically this is step 1):

```
    Dim functOut As String = String.Empty
    Dim wr As Alvas.Audio.IAudioReader = Nothing
    Dim fs As IO.FileStream = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim tmpData() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim dataPCM() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim newFormat As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Try
        Select Case IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower()
            Case ".wav"
                wr = New Alvas.Audio.WaveReader(IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
                filename = IO.Path.GetTempPath & IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) & "2" & IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)
            Case ".mp3"
                wr = New Alvas.Audio.Mp3Reader(IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
            Case Else : wr = New Alvas.Audio.DsReader(filename)
        End Select

        functOut = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, ".wav")

        Dim format As IntPtr = wr.ReadFormat()
        Dim formatDetail As Alvas.Audio.WaveFormat = Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat(format)


        If formatDetail.wFormatTag = Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.MpegLayer3FormatTag Then
            Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.Mp3ToWav(filename, functOut)
            Return True
        Else
            IO.File.Create(functOut).Close()
            While True
                tmpData = wr.ReadData(SECONDS * i, SECONDS)
                If tmpData Is Nothing Or tmpData.Length = 0 Then Exit While

                If formatDetail.wBitsPerSample < 16 Then
                    Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.ToPcm16Bit(format, tmpData, newFormat, dataPCM)
                Else 
                    newFormat = format
                    dataPCM = tmpData
                End If

                formatDetail = Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat(newFormat)

                fs = IO.File.Open(filename, IO.FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                Using ww As New Alvas.Audio.WaveWriter(fs, Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(newFormat))
                    ww.Write(dataPCM, 0, dataPCM.Length())
                End Using

                i += 1
                tmpData = Nothing
            End While
            Return True
        End If

        wr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        filename = String.Empty
        Throw ex
    Finally
        fs.Close()
        wr.Close()
        filename = functOut
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
```

How can I write the resulted stream to be sure I can read it again later?

Any ideas will be great appreciated.

Comment: I lost my attention span trying to figure out why you'd use the "wr" variable name for a stream you *read* from.

Comment: wr (of IAudioReader) it extends filestream from alvas.audio lib to read audioFiles. It holds ways for audio manipulation. (and it should be much easier to use)

Comment: whoa - that was a lot to take in.. can you please simplify the question (remove the other code that may work but has nothing to do with the problem) and please note why your code is nothing like the reference yet it has the same method name, so its easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I hope this is better explained and simplified enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

PCM files are headerless. So when saved, even with waveWriter and the line `Alvas.Audio.AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(newFormat)` was ignored.

Two things can be done:

- find a reader that recognize headerless files and allows to read from it.
- refactor code to decode into PCM file and encode it into the new format (e.g .mp3) without writing the resulted file into File system (much better)